# How to retrieve products by tags (SQL question)

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I have two MySQL tables:

- **product** has *id*, *title*, *price* and some other product attributes
- **tag** has *product_id* and *tag_name* fields

each **product** row can have one ore more rows in table **tag** joined by *product_id* field.
Question: how do I select products by *tag_name* and other attributes?
Example: I need to select all books cheaper than $10 and tagged 'foreign' and 'sci-fi'

I know how to select products with one tag (join product and tag by *product_id* and set where clause)
I know how to select products with more than one tag using a stored procedure, however queries take very long time to run. 
Is there a way to avoid stored procedure and still get the result?

**Update**: StackOverflow does something like this when you click "Related Tags" on the right hand side bar. Now, I don't know what architechture their DB has, but the result is fairly quick selection of all questions tagged with multiple tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return any product with price less than 10, and with tag *foreign* or *sci-fi*

How about something like

```
SELECT  p.*
FROM    product p
WHERE   p.price < 10
AND     EXISTS  (
                    SELECT  1
                    FROM    tag t
                    WHERE   p.id = t.product_id
                    AND     t.tag_name IN ('foreign','sci-fi')
                )
```

This will ensure that it has both tags, **assuming that tags has primary key product_id and tag_name**

```
SELECT  p.*
FROM    product p
WHERE   p.price < 10
AND     EXISTS  (
                    SELECT  1
                    FROM    tag t
                    WHERE   p.id = t.product_id
                    AND     t.tag_name IN ('foreign','sci-fi')
                    HAVING COUNT(1) = 2
                )
```

Comment: tags has a primary key which is a separate field altogether (id). Does your second query also assume the existence of the product_id/tag_name primary key in tags table?

Comment: Your second example produced the desired result (even though I don't have the needed primary key). I will profile it now and see if it is faster than my stored procedures

Comment: The second example does the trick indeed and works several times faster than stored procedures I used before. I don't have a primary key but just a regular index on the two field. Thanks!
P.S. How do I flag my question as answered now? :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be simple query, if I have the problem right.

What I see is:

```
Select Product.* 
from Product, Tag
where Product.id = Tag.product_id
and Product.price<$10
and tag.tag_name in ('foreign', 'sci-fi')
```

Comment: This returns products tagged 'foreign' or 'sci-fi'. The desired result is to return products that have both tag names in the tag table

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
SELECT p.* FROM products p 
INNER JOIN tag t ON p.id = t.product_id 
WHERE p.price < 10 AND p.id IN( SELECT product_id FROM tag  WHERE  t.tag_name = 'foreign' OR t.tag_name = 'sci-fi' GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(product_id) = 2)
```

Comment: None of these work. They all return products tagged as 'foreign' or 'sci-fi', what I need is to required that both 'foreign' _and_ 'sci-fi' tags be present in tag table for the desired product.

Comment: ok, for this you just need to replace (t.tag_name = 'foreign' OR t.tag_name = 'sci-fi') with t.tag_name = 'foreign' AND t.tag_name = 'sci-fi' in first query. Ignore later two queries.

Comment: It doesn't return anything now (since each row in tags only has one tag name, not both)

Comment: i have edited as per my understanding your query, hope this helps. Please check now.